# Microsoft.CSharp reference not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm having a problem with `MVC`. The tricky thing is that the problem appeared when I installed `Windows 8` . In `Windows 7` I have never ecountered it. I created a new `MVC 4` project in `Visual Studio 2012` and all my views are messed up ( Viewbag, helpers and everything ). ( framework targeted is 4.5 )

**Error message:** *One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?*

I have tried a lot of stuff. I have read [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are), [another stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115055/why-am-i-getting-one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-can) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568452/dynamic-keyword-problem) ! Nothing works. I have also reinstalled `VS2012`.

Any ideas why that error message appears in every `View`?

Comment: So you are not able to build your solution??? ... have you tried re-registering the assemble in GAC??

Comment: did you try installing mvc 3 and then mvc4

Comment: @ DnshPly9  -  Yes, but it didn't work :( ;   @ saravanan - aren't they already installed in VS 2012?

Comment: How do you know its the csharp reference?

Comment: @Mike  I've read about it on the network

Answer (score 1):

try to install VS2012 Update 3. While the Visual Studio is not running, remove all Bin and Obj  folders. When VS losts in the references it often solves the problems.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try when I arrive at home